# firefox extension button listener

Tags: firefox-addon, addeventlistener

In my extension where the overlay.js comprises of the following events:

```
var sto = 
{
   onLoad: function() {...},
   onMenuItemCommand: function(e) {...},
   onToolbarButtonCommand: function(e) {...},
};

window.addEventListener("load", function () { sto.onLoad(); }, false);
```

I would need a listener fired every time a button is clicked in a loaded page. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution - was quite easy. Ok here is the source:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Interaction_between_privileged_and_non-privileged_pages

and the modified code:

```
var sto = 
{
   onLoad: function() {...},
   onMenuItemCommand: function(e) {...},
   onMouseClick: function(e) {...},
   onToolbarButtonCommand: function(e) {...},
};

window.addEventListener("load", function () { sto.onLoad(); }, false);
document.addEventListener("click", function(e) { sto.onMouseClick(e); }, false, true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I'm not sure if that's what u want but u can try to do an event delegation on the entire document:

```
var document_mouseup_lst    = EventListener.createEventListener();
doc.addEventListener("mouseup", document_mouseup_lst, false);
document_mouseup_lst.addEvent("mouseup", function click(e, callback, object){
    var element = e.target;

    if(element.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'button') {
        if (e.which == 1) { // left click
            // do whatever u want
        } else if (e.which == 2) { // middle click
            // do whatever u want
        }
    }

return false;
});
```

btw in order to create the eventlistener (the EventListener object which got the createEventlistener method) I used this page [Ajaxian >> An alternative way to addEventListener](http://ajaxian.com/archives/an-alternative-way-to-addeventlistener?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ajaxian+%28Ajaxian+Blog%29&utm_content=Netvibes)

Comment: I have to admit I don't quite understand this code and where would I insert it? Isn't there an event in the extension code like this for example: "onMouseClick: function() {...},"   and in this event I would place my function and that's it. Is there a list of events I can use in the extension itself. Could not find any.